# connecting dots with an (animated) path in d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have the following d3js code that I am trying to do two things with--this question is just about the first one:

1) I want to draw a dotted green line between the green dots.

2) Eventually, I want to have an animation that starts with just the red path and when you click the text it transforms the red path into the green one (sort of "sinking down")

Advice on either would be great!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>D3: Labels removed</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../d3/d3.v3.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">

            .axis path,
            .axis line {
                fill: none;
                stroke: black;
                shape-rendering: crispEdges;
            }

            .axis text {
                font-family: sans-serif;
                font-size: 11px;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Click me to move the line[not working yet]</p>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            //Width and height
            var w = 500;
            var h = 300;
            var padding = 30;


            //Static dataset
            var dataset = [
                            [2,13],[5, 21], [7,22],[8,28],[10, 30], [12, 34], [13,36],[16,42],[17, 44]
                          ];

            var dataset2 = [
                            [12, 28], [13,26],[16,19],[17, 13]
                          ];

            //Create scale functions
            var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
                                 .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return d[0]; })])
                                 .range([padding, w - padding * 2]);

            var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
                                 .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return d[1]; })])
                                 .range([h - padding, padding]);

            // var rScale = d3.scale.linear()
            //                   .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return d[1]; })])
            //                   .range([2, 5]);

            //Define X axis
            var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                              .scale(xScale)
                              .orient("bottom")
                              .ticks(5);

            //Define Y axis
            var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                              .scale(yScale)
                              .orient("left")
                              .ticks(5);


            //Create SVG element
            var svg = d3.select("body")
                        .append("svg")
                        .attr("width", w)
                        .attr("height", h);

            //Create circles


            svg.append("g")
               .selectAll("circle")
               .data(dataset)
               .enter()
               .append("circle")
               .attr("cx", function(d) {
                    return xScale(d[0]);
               })
               .attr("cy", function(d) {
                    return yScale(d[1]);
               })
               .attr("r", function(d) {
                    return 5;})
               .attr("fill", function(d){
                    if (d[0] > 11) {return "red";}
                    else return "black";

               });

            svg.append("g")
               .selectAll("circle")
               .data(dataset2)
               .enter()
               .append("circle")
               .attr("cx", function(d) {
                    return xScale(d[0]);
               })
               .attr("cy", function(d) {
                    return yScale(d[1]);
               })
               .attr("r", function(d) {
                    return 5;
               })
               .attr("fill", "green");

            //Create X axis
            svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h - padding) + ")")
                .call(xAxis);

            //Create Y axis
            svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + padding + ",0)")
                .call(yAxis);

            //Create dividing line
            svg.append("line")
                .attr("x1", xScale(dataset[0][0]))
                .attr("y1", yScale(dataset[0][1]))
                .attr("x2", xScale(dataset[4][0]))
                .attr("y2", yScale(dataset[4][1]))
                .attr("stroke", "black")
                .attr("stroke-width", 2)
                .attr("stroke-dasharray", "5,5");
            svg.append("line")
                .attr("x1", xScale(dataset[4][0]))
                .attr("y1", yScale(dataset[4][1]))
                .attr("x2", xScale(dataset[8][0]))
                .attr("y2", yScale(dataset[8][1]))
                .attr("stroke", "red")
                .attr("stroke-width", 2)
                .attr("stroke-dasharray", "5,5");

            svg.append("line")
                .attr("x1", xScale(11))
                .attr("y1", 0)
                .attr("x2", xScale(11))
                .attr("y2", h-padding)
                .attr("stroke", "black")
                .attr("stroke-width", 2)
                .attr("stroke-dasharray", "5,5");
            d3.select("p")
                .on("click", function() {
                    //code for moving line goes here    
                });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to connect the green dots is a [path generator](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#path-data-generators):

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d) { return xScale(d[0]); })
  .y(function(d) { return yScale(d[1]); });

greenG
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", line(dataset2))
  .style("fill", "none")
  .style("stroke", "green")
  .style("stroke-dasharray", "5,5");
```

Your falling line is a little more complex.  Here's one implementation:

```
// create an array of "interpolaters" for each point to be moved
// from the greenSet to the redSet
var interpolaters = [];
greenSet.forEach(function(d,i){
  interpolaters.push({
    x: d3.interpolate(xScale(redSet[i][0]), xScale(d[0])),
    y: d3.interpolate(yScale(redSet[i][1]), yScale(d[1]))
  })
});

// set up a path generator line function to be used
var fallLine = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d) { return d[0]; })
  .y(function(d) { return d[1]; });

// g to hold our falling line and points
var fallingG = svg.append("g");

// this path is our line
fallingPath = fallingG
  .append("path")
  .style("fill", "none")
  .style("stroke", "steelblue")
  .style("stroke-dasharray", "5,5")
  // set up the transition
  .transition()
  // delay it 1s
  .delay(1000)
  // it'll last 3s
  .duration(3000)
  .ease('linear')
  // custom tween, that'll redraw the line on each animation
  .tween("fallLine", function(d) {
    var path = d3.select(this);
    return function(t) {
      var lineData = [];
      // loop our interpolaters to get current line positions
      interpolaters.forEach(function(i){
        lineData.push([i.x(t),i.y(t)]);
      });
      path.attr("d", fallLine(lineData));
    };
  });

// similar code for our circles
fallingG
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(interpolaters)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .style("fill","steelblue")
  .attr("r", 5)
  .transition()
  .delay(1000)
  .duration(3000)
  .ease('linear')
  // here we can use attrTween instead of a custom tween
  .attrTween("cx", function(d){
    return d.x;
  })
  .attrTween("cy", function(d){
    return d.y;
  });
```

Full working code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>D3: Labels removed</title>
  <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    .axis path,
    .axis line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: black;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }
    
    .axis text {
      font-family: sans-serif;
      font-size: 11px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <p>Click me to move the line[not working yet]</p>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    //Width and height
    var w = 500;
    var h = 300;
    var padding = 30;


    //Static dataset
    var blackSet = [
      [2, 13],
      [5, 21],
      [7, 22],
      [8, 28],
      [10, 30]
    ];
    
    var redSet = [
      [12, 34],
      [13, 36],
      [16, 42],
      [17, 44]
    ];

    var greenSet = [
      [12, 28],
      [13, 26],
      [16, 19],
      [17, 13]
    ];

    //Create scale functions
    var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(redSet, function(d) {
        return d[0];
      })])
      .range([padding, w - padding * 2]);

    var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(redSet, function(d) {
        return d[1];
      })])
      .range([h - padding, padding]);

    // var rScale = d3.scale.linear()
    //                   .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return d[1]; })])
    //                   .range([2, 5]);

    //Define X axis
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(xScale)
      .orient("bottom")
      .ticks(5);

    //Define Y axis
    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(yScale)
      .orient("left")
      .ticks(5);


    //Create SVG element
    var svg = d3.select("body")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", w)
      .attr("height", h);

    //Create circles
    svg.append("g")
      .selectAll("circle")
      .data(blackSet)
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return xScale(d[0]);
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return yScale(d[1]);
      })
      .attr("r", function(d) {
        return 5;
      })
      .attr("fill", "black");

    svg.append("g")
      .selectAll("circle")
      .data(redSet)
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return xScale(d[0]);
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return yScale(d[1]);
      })
      .attr("r", function(d) {
        return 5;
      })
      .attr("fill", "red");
    
    var greenG = svg.append("g");
    
    greenG
      .selectAll("circle")
      .data(greenSet)
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return xScale(d[0]);
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return yScale(d[1]);
      })
      .attr("r", function(d) {
        return 5;
      })
      .attr("fill", "green");
      
    var line = d3.svg.line()
      .x(function(d) { return xScale(d[0]); })
      .y(function(d) { return yScale(d[1]); });
      
    greenG
      .append("path")
      .attr("d", line(greenSet))
      .style("fill", "none")
      .style("stroke", "green")
      .style("stroke-dasharray", "5,5");
  
    //Create X axis
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h - padding) + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

    //Create Y axis
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + padding + ",0)")
      .call(yAxis);

    //Create dividing line
    svg.append("line")
      .attr("x1", xScale(blackSet[0][0]))
      .attr("y1", yScale(blackSet[0][1]))
      .attr("x2", xScale(blackSet[4][0]))
      .attr("y2", yScale(blackSet[4][1]))
      .attr("stroke", "black")
      .attr("stroke-width", 2)
      .attr("stroke-dasharray", "5,5");
      
    svg.append("line")
      .attr("x1", xScale(redSet[0][0]))
      .attr("y1", yScale(redSet[0][1]))
      .attr("x2", xScale(redSet[3][0]))
      .attr("y2", yScale(redSet[3][1]))
      .attr("stroke", "red")
      .attr("stroke-width", 2)
      .attr("stroke-dasharray", "5,5");

    svg.append("line")
      .attr("x1", xScale(11))
      .attr("y1", 0)
      .attr("x2", xScale(11))
      .attr("y2", h - padding)
      .attr("stroke", "black")
      .attr("stroke-width", 2)
      .attr("stroke-dasharray", "5,5");
    d3.select("p")
      .on("click", function() {
        //code for moving line goes here    
      });
      
    var interpolaters = [];
     greenSet.forEach(function(d,i){
      interpolaters.push({
        x: d3.interpolate(xScale(redSet[i][0]), xScale(d[0])),
        y: d3.interpolate(yScale(redSet[i][1]), yScale(d[1]))
      })
    });
    
    var fallLine = d3.svg.line()
      .x(function(d) { return d[0]; })
      .y(function(d) { return d[1]; });
    
    var fallingG = svg.append("g");
    
    fallingPath = fallingG
      .append("path")
      .style("fill", "none")
      .style("stroke", "steelblue")
      .style("stroke-dasharray", "5,5")
      .transition()
      .delay(1000)
      .duration(3000)
      .ease('linear')
      .tween("fallLine", function(d) {
        var path = d3.select(this);
        return function(t) {
          var lineData = [];
          interpolaters.forEach(function(i){
            lineData.push([i.x(t),i.y(t)]);
          });
          path.attr("d", fallLine(lineData));
        };
      });
      
    fallingG
      .selectAll("circle")
      .data(interpolaters)
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .style("fill","steelblue")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .transition()
      .delay(1000)
      .duration(3000)
      .ease('linear')
      .attrTween("cx", function(d){
        return d.x;
      })
      .attrTween("cy", function(d){
        return d.y;
      });

  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I learned so much reading through your code. Really appreciate it.